# Why only the first dictionary get written in the csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv, io

I use `IMDbPY` library to get for example 100 movies info and store them in the csv file. The problem is only the first movie information in the loop would be written in the csv file.

here is the code :

```
from imdb import IMDb
import csv
from datetime import datetime

startTime = datetime.now()

ia = IMDb()
movie_id = 2250912

for i in range(1, 101):
    movie = ia.get_movie(movie_id)
    movie_id += i

    print(datetime.now() - startTime)
    print (movie_id)
    print ('\n')

    with open('dict.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

        for key, value in movie.items():
            writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: `w` flag is used for `writing`. So basically your file gets overwritten 100 times losing previous data each time. To keep the previous data, use `a` flag which stands for *append*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your with statement overwrites the csv every iteration of the while loop. Use `'a'` instead of `'w'` so the information gets appended.